# how to properly express "begin not to do something"

Tags: expressions

how to properly express "begin not to do something"

for example:

> I begin not to be worried about him
>        something like: I begin to stop worrying about him
>
> I begin not to love her
>        something like: I begin to stop loving her

are there any other expressions?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

*I stopped worrying about him* (implies the change of state, not the continuing state).

More colloquially: *I gave up worrying about him*

More formally: *I ceased worrying about him*

Comment: That is not the beginning of the end, but the end itself. "I am ceasing to worry about him" would be the beginning

Comment: +1 but I would use the present participle - *giving up* or *ceasing*

Answer (score 2):

These are examples of typical ways to express that transition:

> - I am starting to fall out of love with her.
> - I am starting to lose patience with him.
> - I am starting to not worry about him.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

> - *easing up* on my worrying ...
> - *letting go* of my worrying ...
> - *relenting* in my worrying ...
> - *forgoing* my worrying ...
> - *tapering off* my worrying ...

[Note that the various alternatives have a range (or absence) of associated prepositions.]

Answer (score 0):

Consider  *[desist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desist)*, which means “To cease to proceed or act; to stop; to forbear” (and also consider *[forbear](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forbear#Verb)*,  “To refrain from proceeding; to pause; to delay”).  Eg:

> After a few days of telling the same story, they desisted.
>   They desisted in their worry when his temperature receded.